# How to rotate logs daily in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, log-rotation

I want to rotate rabbitmq logs daily. It is mentioned in the following link that rotation can be configured using following properties.
log.file.rotation.date, log.file.rotation.size, log.file.rotation.count.
 https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html

how can I configure daily rotation using these parameters?

Comment: Are you saying you do not understand the document? The samples too are given in the document. Try for yourself to understand than asking people to make you understand the documentation. You could ask if after you have tried, something's not working.

Comment: In the example they gave log.file.rotation.date="". What does "" mean? What are the other possible values ?. It is not documented properly over there. Thats the reason why I asked this question, so that someone who solved this task before can help me.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ use basho lager as a logging framework. More info about parameters can be found here: https://github.com/basho/lager#internal-log-rotation